# Handle exception in print class

Tags: android, printing

I am working on printing a bitmap on android. I'm running into a problem where I get an Illegal State Exception. This only occurs when I call "print" two times very quick.How to handle exception in Print Class.Code shown below

```
public void print(Bitmap bitmap){ 
    PrintHelper   photoPrinter = new   PrintHelper(this); 
    photoPrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT); 
    photoPrinter.printBitmap("droids.jpg - test print", bitmap); 
}
```

---

Comment: Please add the full stacktrace. And to ignore these exceptions, add a try-catch statement

Comment: "print" is a button?

Comment: yes "print " is button

Answer (score 0):

variable to track event time

```
private long mLastClickTime = 0;
```

and start of the method add the below code

```
if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000) {
       return;
}
mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
```